# Button proprieties changed when change CSS class name

Tags: html, css

The below code used for button in my website i tried to use it for another button with different button, i have tried to change the class name from " set_3_button3 "  to " set_35_button35 " also " set_3_button3 fav" but the problem is the whole design changed and did not appear the same as the original one

```css
.set_3_button3 {
 color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
 -o-transition: all 0.5s;
 transition: all 0.5s;
 position: relative;
 background:#ffe826;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: auto;
 padding: 0px 25px;
 margin-right: 2.5em;
 line-height: 45px;
 float: left;
 cursor: pointer;
 text-align: center;
}
.set_3_button3  a {
 color: rgba(51,51,51,1);
 text-decoration: none;
 display: block;
}
.set_3_button3 span {
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s;
 transition: all 0.3s;
}
.set_3_button3:hover {
 background-color:#dd483f;
}
.set_3_button3:hover > span {
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 40px);
 transform: translate(0px, 40px);
}
.set_3_button3::after {
 content: attr(data-text);
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transform: translate(30%, 0);
 transform: translate(30%, 0);
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s;
 transition: all 0.3s;
}
.set_3_button3:hover::after {
 opacity: 1;
 -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
 transform: translate(0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="set_3_button3" data-text="Add to favorite"><span> <i class="fa fa-star fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; Add to favorite </span></div>
```

Comment: show the code for both html buttons, it might be useful to include surrounding elements too as its possible they are affecting the code. Note also adding fav after the class like that targets a child element <fav> in any element with the class .set_3_button3

Comment: Then you have to copy CSS code of "set_3_button3" and paste it in new class "set_35_button35".

Comment: @SudhirKaushik  thanks for your reply guys but i have already post the css code have you see it ??

Comment: I don't see "set_35_button35" anywhere in CSS.

Comment: @SudhirKaushik the code of set_35_button35 is the same of set_3_button3. the only thing i just changed the name that its

Comment: Then you have to provide complete code; HTML and CSS. Can't figure out your problem from provided set of code.

Comment: @Simon you say your problem is that you have 2 buttons and they look different, even though they have the same css. So _that_ is what you need to show here: 2 buttons that have the same css, but look different.

Comment: Per your post: "i tried to use it for another button with different button". You have not supplied code showing markup for both the working and nonworking version only the button code. While it may seem like it shouldnt matter what surrounds it, when it comes to styling it very much can. do you have an accessible page where we can view both buttons in action?